# GCC compilation within docker with "-j"

Tags: docker, gcc

I got strange errors while compiling my project within the docker container when I am using `-j` option of `make`.

The errors look like this:

```
/root/projects/obj/linux_debug/src/myos_make/libmyos.a: error adding symbols: Cannot allocate memory
/usr/protobuf-3.9.2/lib/libprotobuf.a: error adding symbols: Bad address
```

Compiling the same project inside the container without `-j` and outside the container with `-j` passes ok.

The Dockerfile :

```
#
# This docker must be built from projects/src folder as context
#

FROM ubuntu:18.04 as base

# copy the dockerfile to make it possible to keep track of the cntent of the image
COPY ./docker_build/docker_files/Dockerfile.ubuntu18.04-builder $HOME/.

# Disable Prompt During Packages Installation
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update Ubuntu Software repository
RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y

# Install base utils
RUN apt install -y \
       nano \
       wget \
       sudo \
       curl \
       && apt clean -y 


# Install additional packages needed for build.
RUN apt install -y \
       nasm \
       pkg-config \
       bc \
       python \
       python3 \
       python3-pip \
       sshpass \
       libapr1 \
       libapr1-dev \
       && apt clean -y 

RUN apt install -y  \
       rpm \
       libaio-dev \
       libnuma-dev \
       numactl \
       valgrind \
       openssl \
       libssl-dev \
       ldap-utils \
       libldap2-dev \
       libncurses5-dev \
       libncursesw5-dev \
       uuid-dev \
       ncurses-base \
       expat \
       libfuse-dev \
       cmake \
       build-essential \
       autotools-dev \
       autoconf \
       automake \
       doxygen \
       linux-headers-4.15.0-173-generic \
       g++-multilib \
       lib32z1-dev \
       libasan4 \
       software-properties-common \
       libtool \
       unzip \
       xsltproc \
       && apt clean -y 

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/doxygen /bin/doxygen

# install GCC compiler
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y \
       && apt update -y\
       && apt install gcc-10 -y \
       && apt install g++-10 -y \
       && apt clean -y && \
       update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-10 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-10 && \
       update-alternatives --config gcc 

RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py && \
       python get-pip.py

RUN ln -sf /usr/local/bin/pip2 /usr/bin/pip
RUN pip install \
       pyyaml \
       jinja2 \
       gcovr


FROM base as env-prepare

COPY external/protobuf /protobuf

RUN cd protobuf  && ./build_proto.sh

FROM base as builder

COPY --from=env-prepare /usr/protobuf-3.9.2/ /usr/protobuf-3.9.2/
COPY --from=env-prepare /usr/protobuf-c-1.3.2/ /usr/protobuf-c-1.3.2/

COPY docker_build/docker-image-release /etc/docker-image-release

ARG UID=1000
USER ${UID}

# This entrypoint is to make everything run inside bash, so the devtools script will alway run before the command
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c" ]
```

Comment: We need to see your Makefile, not your Dockerfile.

Comment: ...in general, having race conditions exposed by `make -j` means your makefile has operations with side effects that aren't properly declared as inputs/outputs for use in sorting the dependency tree. Why this only happens in a container is something that _could_ be investigated, but that investigation is unlikely to be worth the time spent; better to fix the makefile so the race condition is impossible than to dig into figuring out why the race condition happens in circumstance A but not circumstance B.

Comment: (often, some slight variance on circumstance-A is all it takes -- maybe you have a change to system load or `nprocs` or the amount of memory allocated to the block cache and all of a sudden the problem starts happening outside the container too; spending your time tracking down the immediate cause of the symptom can be a never-ending battle, much better to just fix the root cause)

Comment: ...for that matter, have you evaluated whether "can't allocate memory" means exactly what it says? There _is_ extra memory load created by using a container (you've got both your host's libc and other shared libraries as well as the separate libc &c used by the container)

Comment: (sometimes "can't allocate memory" means the field being used to determine how much memory _needs_ to be allocated has a corrupt value in it, and the software is asking the OS for an absurd amount; but sometimes it means you have overcommit turned off and genuinely don't have available physical memory to map a new allocation of virtual memory into -- and if you're running more processes in parallel, of course, you've got more draw on that limited resource).

Comment: Anyhow -- for the moment, I'm voting to close this question as lacking a [mre], as even though you've provided a Dockerfile, just running that Dockerfile doesn't try to download and build `myos`, so we can't reproduce the issue ourselves. (Even _failing_ to reproduce the issue using the same code would be a useful datapoint, as it would support the theory that what we're running into is a host-specific resource-availability limitation)